# Creating regular Expression in Java

Tags: regex, string, validation

Required Expression Format:`a-b-c-d-e-f` or `b-c-e-d`
There is  limit for the string minimum 3 and maximum 11

```
^[([a-f])\-([a-f])\-([a-f])\-([a-f])\-([a-f])\-([a-f])]{3,11}$
```

Doesn't suit the requirement but it works in  [test regular Expression in ruby](http://rubular.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
^[a-f](?:-[a-f]){2,10}$
```

`{2,10}` range quantifier which repeats the previous token `(?:-[a-f])` from 2 to 10 times.

[DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/zJrTvGccMh)

Comment: can we avoid repetition eg:c-c-d

Answer (score 0):

based on OP's last comment to avoid repetition and to modify Avinash Raj's pattern

```
^(?!\S*([a-f])-\1)([a-f](?:-[a-f]){2,10})$
```

Edited:

```
^(?!\S*([a-f]+)\S*-\1(?:-|$))[a-f](-[a-f]){2,10}
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/fylmWm28gX)

Comment: Thank you alpha  bravo, unfortunately that doesn't work

Comment: @tom030888, I thought you meant consecutive repetition, updated my answer above.